# Extract list subset with 2 conditions (only working with 1) on Google Sheets

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula

I'm using this formula to extract, in another tab, a list of IDs (from the *id* named range (column)) that fulfill the following condition: the value in the named range (column) *gc* isn't equal to *Gift Card* for this ID.

```
=IFERROR(ArrayFormula(INDEX(id,SMALL(IF(gc<>"Gift Card",ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&ROWS(gc)))),ROWS($2:2)))),"")
```

This works perfectly fine, I have my reduced list of IDs in the other tab.
The problem is, I'm trying to **add a second condition** with the same logic :

```
lg<>"EN"
```

where *lg* is a named range (column) with the same length as *gc*

But can't make it work!

Here is what I've tried:

```
=IFERROR(ArrayFormula(INDEX(id,SMALL(IF(AND(gc<>"Gift Card",lg<>"EN"),ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&ROWS(gc)))),ROWS($2:2)))),"")
```

But when I enter the formula, nothing appears in my cell anymore.

Comment: kindly add google sheets tag, because it is not related to normal excel.

Comment: Hi, thanks I will do this now. I use Excel in French so I thought "English Excel" was like Google Sheets, my bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this works:

```
=FILTER(id, gc<>"Gift Card", lg<>"EN")
```